# Node.JS app running on AWS performance issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, networking, pm2

I have been experiencing ambiguous performance issues with a NodeJS with MYSQL app for a while,
In a nutshell, certain requests take a very long time to return a response to the browser. 
*up to 20 seconds in some cases*

using chrome devtools to monitor timing, data in the Time column below shows significant variations between response time to the **same endpoint**.

[image]

To further investigate the issue, I set up the code below to one of the endpoints handlers to monitor delays in the console, In this example, I am running the app on my local PC, and connecting it to a remote production database on the server.

```js
async function getSomething(param) {
  const start = new Date().getTime();
  const something = await Model.where({ field: param }).fetch();
  const end = new Date().getTime();
  console.log('delay: ', end - start, 'ms');
  return something;
}
```

I executed ten requests to **one endpoint**, data below shows delays logged to console VS time it takes to get data back to the browser.

*numbers are in milliseconds*
[image]

some responses return back to the browser with almost no or very minor delay as shown in the second and last row, whereas some other requests show a major difference in the time it takes data to be fetched from the database, and the time it needs to be sent to the browser. and this happens in most cases.
some other cases data takes a really long time to be fetched only from the database as shown in row number 3.

differences are arbitrary to me which made it hard to find a pattern to the problem.

---

here is a screenshot to the app instance metrics from my amazon console, It might help someone to spot something that could help.

[image]

---

furthermore, I am using PM2 process manager to manage the app on the server, and this is another screenshot of the app metrics analysis.

[image]

I would really appreciate if someone could point a finger on where else could I look to identify and fix the issue.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the nodejs application is running some long synchronous operations that stall the event loop. This can be seen in the relatively big event loop latency in the PM2 screenshot.

This can happen due to:

- The code is running time consuming computational operations using
- some sync functions for accessing external resources like for example fs.readFileSync

This can be while processing other parallel requests or timers not related to the request you are debugging.

A nodejs application runs in a single thread, and it depends that all code paths return fast to the event loop so it can process next event.

I suggest profiling the application (https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/) and looking for longest running functions and concentrate on the functions taking long time.

Comment: I followed the article, what I got in the Summary section is slightly similar to results in the article except with differences in the percentage of delay caused by C++ code vs javascript code,  on the C++ section, the first and most significant record is this 
8084   28.9%   29.8%  epoll_pwait,
I looked it up and I found that its a Linux related function that should wait for I/O events, blocking the calling thread if no events are currently available.
this isn't very useful to me in this case.

Comment: any ideas what could help identify and solve the issue?
thanks anyway

Comment: What about the javascript section?

Comment: JavaScript section makes up 30% of the time taken to finish a request, and this 30 % is scattered across many sub-processes, with the first entry account for only 2.5% of CPU time taken by a function called LoadIC!
does this ring a bell to you!?

Comment: but still, even if it does and we got rid of it, that means we only reduced 2.5% of the time.

Comment: just to not lose focus, the target is not general performance tuning. My hypothesis the cause of you issue is that:
* there is end point 1 which should run fast and you measure its response
* there is end point 2, or some other background job, that sometimes run in parallel with end point 1. End point 2 executes some heavy operation like a long loop, iterates a large number of array entries, or executes some async function like file operation.

either you know the code and can identify if this is the case, or profiling can give you a hint.

Comment: In short, the issue was in database queries, the project is relatively big and the number of users increased over time. many cron jobs are running db queries and API calls every minute. what finally helped reduce performance deficiency is optimization to database queries, this is achieved by minimizing database calls and by fetching data from multiple tables in one query as opposed to separate multiple ones. thanks for your suggestions anyway. شكرا :)